# Oring of outputs in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I have generated 15 modules using generate having `m[0:14]` outputs. I want to `or` them together. Will this work?

```
if (m == 1)begin
result = 1;
end
```

Or, if not, then what is the optimum way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for reduction operations in verilog.

```
( |m ) = m[1] | m[2] | m[3] ...
```

http://www.ee.ed.ac.uk/~gerard/Teach/Verilog/manual/Operators/reduction.html

Answer (score 3):

`assign result = |m;` should work. The `|` is a unary reduction or, which `or`s all of the bits of m together.

What you have will not work, because it will compare `m` to `'d1`, which will be true iff m is `000000000000001`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this will also work:

```
if (m) result = 1;
```

Since `|m` is implicitly executed to convert values to booleans